# why is using any() results in maximum recursion depth

Tags: python, any

long story short, I wrote a recursive function to solve a problem. The problem itself doesn't matter, but I will briefly introduce:

To find out whether a word can be found in a matrix of strings. 
The recursion requires to find a match on a letter, then search the neighbors (up, down, left, right) to find the next letter. If it eventually leads to a path that finds all letters then the word is found.

The recursive function is `finder`

```
def finder(self, board: List[List[str]], word: str, idx: int, coor: Tuple[int, int], prev: Dict[Tuple[int], int]):
    N = len(word)
    x, y = coor[0], coor[1]
    row, col = len(board), len(board[0])
    if idx == N: 
        return True
    elif not 0 <= x < row or not 0 <= y < col:  
        return False
    elif coor in prev:
        return False
    elif board[x][y] != word[idx]:
        return False
    else:
        new_prev = prev.copy()
        new_prev[coor] = 1 

        up = (x - 1, y)
        down = (x + 1, y)
        left = (x, y - 1)
        right = (x, y + 1)

        # Old
        # return any([self.finder(board, word, idx + 1, new_coor, new_prev) for new_coor in [up, down, left, right]])

        # New
        return self.finder(board, word, idx + 1, up, new_prev) or \
               self.finder(board, word, idx + 1, down, new_prev) or \
               self.finder(board, word, idx + 1, left, new_prev) or \
               self.finder(board, word, idx + 1, right, new_prev)
```

In the codes, I first tried a one liner:

```
return any([finder(board, word, idx + 1, new_coor, prev) for new_coor in [up, down, left, right]])
```

It costed me maximum recursion when the matrix is big and the word is long. But I couldn't figure out a better algorithm, until I saw the answer, which is almost identical to mine, but only the last part using:

```
return finder(board, word, idx + 1, up, prev) or \
       finder(board, word, idx + 1, down, prev) or \
       finder(board, word, idx + 1, left, prev) or 
       finder(board, word, idx + 1, right, prev)
```

And that solves the problem.

Now I am confused, I thought the two return has the same meaning, except that using any allows a one-liner, which is more elegant...so what is the difference here?

Thanks!

Comment: And `finder` is what exactly?

Comment: @StephenRauch basically a tree recursive function that divide into 4 direction, and return should be a `boolean`

Comment: That is not *exactly*...

Comment: ok, I'll post it then

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an exhaustive list, *then* passing that to `any()`. Observe:

```py
>>> def thing(x):
...   print(x)
...   return True
...
>>> any(thing(y) for y in (1, 2, 3, 4))
1
True
>>> any([thing(y) for y in (1, 2, 3, 4)])
1
2
3
4
True
```

Notice how in the latter case you are using a list comprehension to populate the full list and only then passing it to `any` for evaluation.

Comment: This does show a difference. But in my case, removing the list still will reach to maximum recursion depth.